# Squid takes 2 minutes to cache a small pdf

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

We are having a problem that certain pdf from a specific url take a long time to display. Squid seems to use a long time to cache it (over 2 minutes) for 110kb. If I browse this pdf without going through squid it works perfectly.

```
1359106030.833 120114 160.85.85.46 TCP_MISS/200 116194 GET http://www2.zhlex.zh.ch/appl/zhlex_r.nsf/0/9429732E0BEDB5EDC12574C60044A4CC/$file/xxx.pdf - DIRECT/195.65.218.66 application/pdf
```

You can also see the gap on tcpdump

[image]

It exists on our Squid 3.1 but also on Squid 3.2. It only occurs on pdfs from that url. Other pdf are working fine.

It can not be their server as it works smooth without going through the proxy

This is our sanitized config. It has been taken over from old squid versions and have not been ajusted since then.

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl bigip src xx.xx.xx.xx/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl monhost   src xx.xx.xx.xx/32
acl srv-ts-057   src xx.xx.xx.xx/32
acl srv-ts-058   src xx.xx.xx.xx/32
acl snmppublic snmp_community Fast3thernet
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/16       # xx
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/32   # HSWNAT
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/16           # VoIP
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/22       # HAP
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/22      # HSSAZ
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24       # Management Netz 1
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24       # Management Netz 2
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # FET-DEV
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # FET-TEST
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # BET-DEV
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # BET-TEST
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # FET-VDP
acl xxnet src xx.xx.xx.xx/24      # FET-VDP
acl STAFFMGR src xx.xx.xx.xx/26
acl SSL_ports port 443 8443 28443 50001
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl MONxxCH dstdomain mon.xx.ch
acl ZREG dstdomain zreg.xx.ch
acl PUT method PUT
http_access allow PUT xxnet
http_access deny PUT
acl PURGE method PURGE
http_access allow PURGE localhost
http_access deny PURGE
acl PROPFIND method PROPFIND
http_access allow PROPFIND srv-ts-057
http_access allow PROPFIND srv-ts-058
http_access deny PROPFIND
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny to_localhost
http_access deny !STAFFMGR MONxxCH
http_access deny !STAFFMGR ZREG
http_access allow xxnet
http_access deny all
icp_access deny all
follow_x_forwarded_for allow localhost
follow_x_forwarded_for allow bigip
acl_uses_indirect_client on
delay_pool_uses_indirect_client on
log_uses_indirect_client on
http_port 160.85.104.11:8080
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
cache_mem 768 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 32 KB
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid 25000 64 256
coredump_dir /var/cache/squid
#access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
#cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_store_log none
#pid_filename /var/run/squid.pid
ftp_user wwwuser@xx.ch
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
acl shoutcast rep_header X-HTTP09-First-Line ^ICY.[0-9]
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
request_timeout 30 seconds
cache_mgr servicedesk@xx.ch
#mail_from squid@srv-app-901.xx.ch
#mail_program /usr/local/bin/mutt
cache_effective_user squid
cache_effective_group squid
httpd_suppress_version_string on
visible_hostname srv-app-901.xx.ch
unique_hostname srv-app-901.xx.ch
snmp_port 3401
snmp_access allow snmppublic monhost
snmp_access deny all
snmp_incoming_address xx.xx.xx.xx
snmp_outgoing_address 255.255.255.255
icp_port 0
allow_underscore off
dns_retransmit_interval 3 seconds
dns_timeout 1 minute
dns_nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx
append_domain .xx.ch
max_filedescriptors 8192
```

Any idea what could cause this ?

Comment: The [squid blog](http://squidproxy.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/happy-eyeballs/) confirms incomplete implementation of "[Happy Eyeballs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6555)" in version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

I found out that the command "host www2.zhlex.zh.ch" will end in a timeout. Squid is first looking for an AAAA record (ipv6) but we are not using ipv6. This takes the 2 minutes before it timed out and looked for an A record.

I have disabled ipv6 on the system + I have added the following lines to squid.conf to force ipv4

```
acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
tcp_outgoing_address <your_proxy_ipv4_address> !to_ipv6
```

Now everything works!